# Using Mail::queue with iron.io

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use the **Mail::queue** in Laravel 4 without success.

When I run the command:

```
php artisan queue: subscribe queue_name http://foo.com/queue/push
```

It is created on my dashboard a subscriber, and also when I access my route **queue/send** a new queue is sent to Iron.io.

The problem is that ***I never received the email*** should be sent when the **Mail::queue** to be executed.

Look my routes:

```
<?php
Route::post('queue/push', function() {
        return Queue::marshal();
    });

Route::get('queue/send', function() {
        Mail::queue('emails.teste', array(), function($message) {
                    $message->to('me@mesite.com', 'Renato')->subject('Welcome!');
                });

        return 'Ok';
    });
```

Is there any configuration beyond queues.php I need to do?

When I change the queue/push (for debug) to accept GET and access the URL, the following error appears:

lluminate\Encryption\DecryptException

Invalid data.

Comment: Have you configured your mail credentials in `app/config/mail.php`?

Comment: This properly configured my mail file, if I use Mail::send the email is sent

Comment: Get rid of the space between "queue: subscribe"

Comment: No. Problem is not with my code to send to queue, is receiving

Comment: Your code works fine, I've just tested it on my local machine. I only had to add the `->from("email@site.com")` method. Check that: (1) there are no issues with incoming connections (e.g., firewall); (2) you have specified the correct `queue` name in `app/config/queue.php`; (3) `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` in the `IronCore.class.php` class isn't the culprit; (4) there are no other routes that kick in before `Route::post('queue/push'...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be off, but `Mail::send()` is the correct function to use, since you are using Iron.io to handle the queue.

This should work:

```
Route::get('queue/send', function() {

    Queue::push(function($job) {

        Mail::send('emails.teste', array(), function($message) {
            $message->to('me@mesite.com', 'Renato')->subject('Welcome!');
        });

        $job->delete();
    }

    return 'Ok';
});
```

I'd also suggest checking your Iron.io account to ensure that the 'subscriber' URL is set-up correctly. As Rob W suggests, the space could be causing issues.

Comment: I also thought there was supposed to be a class with a `fire` method in it. I don't use queue's enough...

Comment: Typically you would. For simple tasks like sending out an email, a class might be overkill. L4 also supports pushing a closure onto the queue - [Queueing Closures](http://laravel.com/docs/queues#queueing-closures)

Comment: @timF `Mail:queue` (http://laravel.com/docs/mail#queueing-mail) works with `Iron.io`

Comment: @TimF I just deleted my account and recreated the same Queue in Iron.io and everything worked. VERY strange, if someone go through it, do not waste too much time, delete and recreate the URL in dashboard Iron.io